# ¿Por qué al usar href="mailto:correo" me abre Chrome y no Outlook?

Tags: html, google-chrome, email, internet-explorer

Estoy realizando un codigo sencillo para que me abra un correo colocando `href="mailto:correo@example.com"`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ver</title>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="mailto:kevincs0208@gmail.com.pe">ver resultado</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Resulta que en mi computadora no me direcciona a outlook(que es el correo que tengo instalado), sino que me direcciona a chrome, osea de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero resulta que cuando lo abro desde otra computadora(que esta en red) si se puede abrir, ya que me sale de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué mi computadora lo direcciona a chrome, si es que lo que estoy haciendo en explorer? y ¿Cómo cambiaría para que en mi PC me salga como la segunda imagen?

Comment: Saludos Kevin. No veo nada de php en tu pregunta. Recuerda colocar los tags correspondientes para obtener una respuesta más precisa. Pasate por [ask]

Comment: @AndySamuel gracias por la correccion

Comment: Para solucionar tu problema debes hacer que outlook sea el programa predeterminado para los correos, prueba y comenta qué tal

Comment: si, en las opciones predeterminadas estaba desseleccionado el icono de explorer, tenia que ingresar , marcarlo y luego recien dar aceptar, y ejecuto el codigo sin probllemas... gracias estimado

Comment: Te invito a que respondas la pregunta con los pasos a seguir, así si otra persona tiene el mismo problema pueda resolverlo viendo tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas establecer cómo aplicación predeterminada **Outlook**.

> Archivo > Opciones de Outlook > General > Opciones de Inicio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: claro, eso estaba activado,el cambio era en programas determinados, es alli donde no estaba seleccionado el navegador que estaba usando, igualmente gracias